# Python class self value error, Expected type 'str' got Tuple[str] instead, azure ClientSecretCredential

Tags: python, azure-sdk

I've created a class and trying to assign one of its values to something that expects a string, however it is saying it is getting a `Tuple[str]` instead, and I don't see how?

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential


class ServicePrincipal:
    """
    Service Principal class is used to authorise the service
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.tenant_id = "123-xyz",
        self.client_id = "123-abc",
        self.client_secret = "123-lmn",

    def credentials(self):
        """
        Returns a ClientServiceCredential object using service principal details
        :return:
        """
        # ISSUE IS HERE 
        return ClientSecretCredential(
            tenant_id=self.tenant_id, # <---- Getting Tuple[str]
            client_id=self.client_id, # <---- Getting Tuple[str]
            client_secret=self.client_secret, # <---- Getting Tuple[str]
        )
```

if I copy paste the string directly into the parameter its fine. So the `self.value` is causing an issue somehow?

Comment: Remove the commas from inside your `__init__` method. `"123-xyz",` is a tuple because it has a comma at the end.

Comment: rookie error :( thanks @khelwood

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should remove the commas here:

```py
def __init__(self):
        self.tenant_id = "123-xyz",  # remove the comma
        self.client_id = "123-abc",  # remove the comma
        self.client_secret = "123-lmn",  # remove the comma
```

Comma make the variable be a Tuple